# Setting up the range correctly in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I can't figure out what is the mistake I am making in this code. The error is on setting up the range (line 3 on last loop). Any help would be appreciated. I have lots of code here but i believe all of it is good except in the last loop around p it gives me an error about the range function I believe.

```
              For p = 1 To 100
                    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(p + 26, 10).Value = Sheet3.Cells(6 + k, 4).Value Then
                        Set rng = Sheet3.Range(Cells(k + 6, 5), Cells(k + 6, 12))
                        lAnswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
                        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(p + 27, 13).Value = lAnswer
                        k = k + 1
                    End If
                Next p

    End If
Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the beginning value of k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must qualify both `Range` and `Cells` with the worksheet:

```
Set rng = Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(k + 6, 5), Sheet3.Cells(k + 6, 12))
```

Comment: Hello Roy, I will add the rest of my code. Please look at it when you have time.

Comment: The error is : Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed